# No Way to Query Connecting Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have two tables, A and B with a many-to-many relationship using the connecting table AB.

**Table A**

```
AID int
```

**Table B**

```
BID int
```

**Table AB**

```
AID int
BID int
```

My task is to find all the rows in AB where AB.AID = 2 using linq to entity framework 4.

Part of the problem is that the AB table is not included in the entities model. Only A and B are included with a many-to-many relationship. But since I don't need the information from B, it would be a waste to involve a many-to-many join for this task.

This is trivial using SQL but I don't see how to do it using linq to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best way around this issue is to add a primary key to the AB table such as ABID so that it does appear in your context.

That way your query would look something like this:

```
var q = from ab in context.AB
        where ab.BID == 2
        select ab;
```

I understand this solution is not completely ideal, but it should work.

Comment: Because the AB table must be unique across the two columns, both columns make up a primary key. I would consider this necessary for normalization.

Comment: I would have 3 columns in the AB table, ABID, AID, BID.  The primary key would be ABID and then I'd add unique key / index for AID + BID to prevent duplicates.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense but I don't think an extra column and index is moving in the direction of making this more efficient.

Comment: @Jonathan:  Fair enough.  It definitely is not the most efficient method, but its the best I've found when working with EF.  I'll be interested to see if someone else has a better suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from a in Context.TableA
        where a.TableB != null
        select new 
        {
            AID = a.AID,
            BID = a.TableB.BID
        };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what SQL is used to obtain a.TableB.BID but doesn't it seem horribly inefficient to be looking at TableA and TableB along with some sort of join lookup using a third table when all I need is `SELECT * FROM TableAB WHERE AID=2`? Is EF really this bad?

Comment: IMHO: Don't prematurely optimize. "Bad" is a slow app, not an app which quickly does something in a way which you think *might* be slow.

Comment: Not that I don't appreciate the response but that's a non-answer.

Comment: ??? I gave you an answer which (1) works and (2) should perform fine. Perhaps it's not *precisely* what you're asking for, but I don't see a better suggestion here.

Comment: I didn't mean your answer--I appreciate that. I was talking about the comment above. I've been developing a long time and know how and when to optimize. I just don't know that much about EF.